# Returning rows from a list of indexes in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

## Context

I have a CSV containing two types of rows, an **observation record** and on the row below, an **observation value** which is related to the observation record above. The record line contains a four-letter code which denotes the type of observation. My goal is to create a new CSV containing only those observation records which match a particular list of codes, along with the associated observation values from the row below.

## Example from file

```
OBSERV\LTRC,CL1,0,10.00;
OBVAL\14,,0,V;
OBSERV\LTRC,CL1,10,20.00;
OBVAL\14,,0,V;
OBSERV\LTRC,CL1,20,30.00;
OBVAL\14,,0,V;
OBSERV\LTRC,CL1,30,40.00;
OBVAL\14,,0.5,V;
```

## Code so far

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(r"CSVFILEPATH")
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index
newdf = df.loc[df[0].str.contains('LLRT|LLTX|LRRT|LTRC|LV10|LV3|LEDR|LTRV|LES2|LES1', regex = True)]
# this returns all observation record rows I care about but I still need the associated observation values.

keep_ind = [] #This list will contain all indexes to keep 

observ_ind = ndf.index.values.tolist()#The list of observation record indexes to keep
keep_ind.append(observ_ind)#Added these to the keep_ind list
```

## The Question

How do I take this list of indexes (keep_ind), append a new list which is the same list with 1 added to each item (to get all of the observation value rows beneath the records) and create a new dataframe which contains all of the rows at each of these indexes in this combined list?

So far, I've tried:

```
keep_ind.append(observ_ind + 1 for i in observ_ind)
```

But this gives the error:

```
generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000028057C33648>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to adress two issues. One is how you get your CSV and the other is what probably doesn't work in your code.

## how to get the associated values

What you try to do is a nice task for the `shift()` method

```
# you probably don't need the semicolons at the end of the line, right?
# if you want to get rid of them, you can do:
df= pd.read_csv(
    r"CSVFILEPATH",   # your file
    engine='python',  # use the python engine instead of C to use a regex as separator
    sep=r'[,;]',      # use ; as an alternative separator
    usecols=range(3), # exclude the last column (after the ;)
    names=range(3))   # assign names, if you like you can also assign a list of more verbose column names here (this just uses numbers)

# create a dataframe that is a version of the original
# which is just one row shifted to the top
df_shifted= df.shift(-1)

# concatenate it with the original data frame and assign unique column names
df_concat=  pd.concat([df, df_shifted], axis='columns')
df_concat.columns= range(6)

# apply your filter
newdf= df.loc[df_concat[0].str.contains('LLRT|LLTX|LRRT|LTRC|LV10|LV3|LEDR|LTRV|LES2|LES1', regex = True)]
```

This outputs:

```
In [44]: newdf
Out[44]: 
             0    1     2         3    4    5
0  OBSERV\LTRC  CL1   0.0  OBVAL\14  NaN  0.0
2  OBSERV\LTRC  CL1  10.0  OBVAL\14  NaN  0.0
4  OBSERV\LTRC  CL1  20.0  OBVAL\14  NaN  0.0
6  OBSERV\LTRC  CL1  30.0  OBVAL\14  NaN  0.5
```

From the following test data you provided:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

raw=\
r"""OBSERV\LTRC,CL1,0,10.00;
OBVAL\14,,0,V;
OBSERV\LTRC,CL1,10,20.00;
OBVAL\14,,0,V;
OBSERV\LTRC,CL1,20,30.00;
OBVAL\14,,0,V;
OBSERV\LTRC,CL1,30,40.00;
OBVAL\14,,0.5,V;"""

df= pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(raw), engine='python', sep=r'[,;]', usecols=range(3), names=range(3))
```

## Code, that probably doesn't do, what you intend to do

```
# the following line references a method, but doesn't call it:
df.set_index
# if you execute this line, it outputs:
df.set_index
Out[18]: 
<bound method DataFrame.set_index of              0    1     2
0  OBSERV\LTRC  CL1   0.0
1     OBVAL\14  NaN   0.0
...
# look at the <bound method part, this is the __repr__ string
# of the object (bound methods are objects themselfes)
# if you execute this line inbetween a script, it has no effect
# at all (just maybe slows down execution a very tiny bit)
# because you don't do anything with the returned object
```

You wrote, you get the message `generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000028057C33648>]`. This is not an error method. Like the `bound method` message above, this is also the `__repr__` string of an obect. In this cas a generator object. If you call `append` on a list, it treats the argument passed in `append` as one object. I guess you rather wanted to add the indexes increased by one to an existing list. That can be done with the following code:

```
# create a copy of the list to avoid funny results
new_indices=list(observ_ind)
# add the elements of returned by the generator object
# to the list (rather than the generator object itself
new_indices.extend(i + 1 for i in observ_ind)
```